# Imgproc. resize... doesnt work. i want to resize my image to a smaller one. my second try was to copy my orgimage in a new smaller matrix

Tags: image, resize, size

```
public void findeKarte (Bitmap currentBitmap){

Mat src = new Mat (240, 320, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(255));

      Mat  orgimage = new Mat (currentBitmap.getWidth(), currentBitmap.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

        Utils.bitmapToMat(currentBitmap, orgimage);


        // first try, why doesnt work?

orgimage.copyTo(src);
// second try try
//        Size sz = new Size(240,320);

//          Imgproc.resize(orgimage, src, sz);


        Utils.matToBitmap(src, currentBitmap);
        loadImageToImageView(currentBitmap);
  }


  public void  loadImageToImageView(Bitmap currentBitmap){
      ImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
      ImageView.setImageBitmap(currentBitmap); 

  }
```